# Can I select just one specific element in a sql query(select statement)?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a command line tool that generates a random string(password) of a given length, stores it in a sql db, and can be queried by name. The password generation and storing of it's output by a given name works beautifully, but trying to select only the password element is giving me trouble. I was able to select all from the table but that returns the name and the password. I **only** want the password returned. I thought about just splicing the output or even using the linux `cut` command, but I'd rather just get it from the select statement. Is this possible? My current `SELECT` statement returns: `operation parameter must be a str`. When I try it without the call to `(name)` at the end of the `SELECT` statement like this: `query_password = """SELECT * FROM password_table WHERE name = ?"""` 
I get this error:

```
  File "passbox.py", line 44, in <module>
    query_pswd_by_name(name)
  File "passbox.py", line 39, in query_pswd_by_name
    c.execute(query_password)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

BTW I'm sure my `query_pswd_by_name` function is all wrong, I've been experimenting. When I just create a connection and SELECT statement outside of a function it **does** return the name and password.

Also note that I've disguised my database file's name with asterisks for the purpose of this post. I **am** using an actual working db file in practice.

Here is all the code I've written so far:

````
import secrets 
import string
import sqlite3


#CREATE PASSWORD OF GIVEN LENGTH
def get_pass(length):
        return "".join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.punctuation) for x in range(length))

length = int(input("Enter the length of password: "))
password= get_pass(length)
print(password)


name = str(input("Enter name for password: "))

#CREATE DATABASE CONNECTION
conn = sqlite3.connect("****.db")

#CREATE CURSOR OBJECT
c = conn.cursor()

#CREATE TABLE IN DISK FILE BASED DATABASE
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS password_table (
                        name TEXT,
                        pswd TEXT
                        )""")
c.execute("INSERT INTO password_table (name, pswd) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, password))

#COMMIT CHANGES
conn.commit()
conn.close()

def query_pswd_by_name(name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('****.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    query_password = """SELECT * FROM password_table WHERE name = ?""", (name)
    c.execute(query_password)
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        print(row[1])
    conn.commit()
query_pswd_by_name(name)



#CLOSE CONNECTION
conn.close()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to break up the argument to the execute call.

```
c.execute(*query_password)
```

Or

```
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM password_table WHERE name = ?""", (name))
```